# Taking camera photos in Cocos2d-x?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x-3.0

I saw [Fennex](https://github.com/FenneX/FenneXEmptyProject) attempt to access the camera api of Android within Cocos2dx. But on the project listed, I am not sure how I am going to access the camera and the photogallery. Is there a way to do this in Cocos2dx just as you do with Cocos2d?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[This Post says](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/taking-photos-from-camera-and-gallery/2719/5) there is no cocos2d-x class to do that but provided this code segments:

The gist of it is, on Android :
- call Java code to start an Intent

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
instance.startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 31); //31 is an ID to recognize that intent yourself
```

get the Bitmap returned by the Intent

```
Bitmap original = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");
```

eventually, scale it for your own needs (especially on lower-end device if you also get images from the library)

save it in the file format you want (I use png)

```
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(path);
/* Write bitmap to file using JPEG or PNG and 80% quality hint for JPEG. */
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 80, stream);
bitmap.recycle(); //ensure the image is freed;
stream.close();
```

If you want the same for iOS look at [this post](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/taking-photos-from-camera-and-gallery/2719/7)